# Print all visible rows in QTableView in c++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmodelindex

I have QTableView with 100+ rows in it. But at a time only 6 rows are visible. To see next set of rows, I have to use scrool bar.

I want to print visible rows in QTableView. But could not do that. I could just able to print single selected row.

```
  QItemSelectionModel *select = _table->selectionModel();
  QModelIndexList  selectedRow = select->selectedRows();
  QModelIndex index = selectedRow.at(0);

  int columnCount = 2; // there are 2 columns in a row

  QString copySelectedRowText_;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < columnCount; i++)
  {
      copySelectedRowText_ += index.sibling(index.row(), i).data().toString()+ " ";
  }
  
  qDebug() << copySelectedRowText_;
```

How to print visible rows in QTableView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current line number through the `value()` of the `verticalScrollbar`, and you can also get the number of displayable lines through `pagestep()`.

This is my code ,you can try it:

```
void TesWidget::onbtnClicked()
{
    int start_index = ui.tableView->verticalScrollBar()->value();
    int page_cnt = ui.tableView->verticalScrollBar()->pageStep();
    int end_index = start_index + page_cnt;

    int row_cnt = model_->rowCount();
    int col_cnt = model_->columnCount();

    QString text;
    for (int i = start_index; i < row_cnt && i <= end_index; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col_cnt; j++)
        {
            text.append(QStringLiteral("%1 ").arg(model_->item(i,j)->text()));
        }
        text.append("\n");
    }
    qDebug() << text;
}
```